# About Radon Transform

Tags: image-processing, inverse-problems, tomography

Recently I got to Know that, Radon Transformation has huge contribution to Computer Tomography. So I would like to know about Radon transformation in Mathematical point of view.
Can any one suggest books/good materials for Radon Transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classic in the field is Natterer's [The Mathematics of Computerized Tomography](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-663-01409-6).

Another good book is Helgason's [Radon transform](http://www-math.mit.edu/~helgason/Radonbook.pdf), which is freely available at the author's homepage.

Comment: Is there any free soft copy(ebook) available of this " The Mathematics of Computerized Tomography" book.

Comment: @prasad, I don't know if a free ebook version is available of Natterer's book. At least I've never heard of one, so probably there is no legal free pdf.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorites on the subject is Deans' *The Radon Transform and Some of Its Applications*.

Please see my answer to a similar [stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354006/literature-recommendation-how-to-exactly-obtain-the-inverse-radon-transform) for additional references.